# Instruct Maven to download third party plugin from https://oss.sonatype.org/content

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

There is a plugin I want to use on https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
I know the maven command to run the plugin but how do I instruct Maven where the plugin should be downloaded from ?
I think I need to update my settings file to something like :

```
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>???</id>
        <name>???</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use the configuration in your current for only testing like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
</project>
```

or change your settings appropriately like this:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>apache</id>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>apache.snapshots</id>
          <name>Maven Plugin Snapshots</name>
          <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
</settings>
```

of course with activation of the profile. Or change the configuration of your repository manager.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a repository to your pom, that way the build will remain portable and other developers who build your code will not need to update their settings.xml.

This should do the job:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo-id</id>
        <name>repo-name</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: I can juest recommend to read: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/ cause a repository in a pom is a bad idea and in contradiction: It will make your build not portable.